# Why is CDC::SelectObject virtual only for the CFont version?

Tags: mfc

The [documentation for CDC::SelectObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sa8ahz7h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) states that the "CFont" version is virtual but the CPen, CBrush, CBitmap and CRgn versions are not.

```
CPen* SelectObject(CPen* pPen);
CBrush* SelectObject(CBrush* pBrush );
virtual CFont* SelectObject(CFont* pFont);
CBitmap* SelectObject(CBitmap* pBitmap);
int SelectObject(CRgn* pRgn);
CGdiObject* SelectObject(CGdiObject* pObject);
```

This is quite annoying for me.

Does anybody know the reason for this? I can imagine that it is for performance reasons, for compatibility reasons or maybe just because of the laziness of some Microsoft programmer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the MFC code, it's because CPreviewDC overrides it.

CPreviewDC is a CDC-derived class, used for print preview and which seems to be undocumented. You can find its declaration in `afxpriv.h` and its implementation in `dcprev.cpp`.

EDIT:
Example paths to those files:
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxpriv.h
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\dcprev.cpp

EDIT2: But why aren't they all virtual?

My guess is that Microsoft does not want people messing around with GDI objects (they're a limited resource in the system) and so the functions are declared as non-virtual. They've taken the effort of creating a wrapper around Win32, which handles GDI objects properly (and frees the user from doing most of the handling), and they don't want the users to change that behavior and very probably introduce bugs.

But they had to break that "rule" to be able to implement CPreviewDC, which is a special kind of DC.

All the DCs have two members, m_hDC and m_hAttribDC, which are usually the same. But in CPreviewDC one represents the screen and the other represents the printer. And fonts are a special thing, because the printer does not necessarily have the same fonts as the computer. So, when MFC needs to  prepare the document for print preview, it first selects the font on the printer (it tells the printer (driver) "hey, I need to select this font", and the printer selects the closest font it can) and then CPreviewDC mirrors it to display it on the screen (it selects the closest font available on the system to the one selected by the printer).

The rest of GDI objects, pens, brushes, regions... don't require such special treatment and therefore they are not declared virtual.

Comment: That explains why `CFont* CDC:SelectObject(CFont* pFont)` is virtual but it doesn't explain why e.g. `CBrush* CDC::SelectObject(CBrush* pBrush );` is **not** virtual.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

As written in a previous answer CPreviewDC overwrites SelectObject for a font.

The reason is simple. The fonts on a printer and on the screen are different due to the font mapper.
So the trick is that SelectObject(CFont*) sets an internal variable m_hPinterFont when it is called. Also MirrotFont is called and m_hFont is filled  That's the font that should be used on a screen DC.

Brushes, pens don't need such mapping, because only the Font handling on the devices is very special.

This is partially describes in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edak6tf8.aspx).

HTH